# Save email opens / clicks to Data Extension and create Lead in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder

I'am relativly new to the MC enviroment and to learn i wanted to create my first MC Projekt / Journey.

I made some thoughts about how i would like create logics / Journey / Activations for my learing path in Marketing Cloud but  I`am not sure if my ideas are creatable and working in MC. The Marketing Cloud Connector is already installed and MC is connected with SalesCloud.

Could you please give me advice on that if its best practice or maybe better ways to accomplish my needs.

**1.    I have the Data Extension "SebastianDE" --> I will use SmartCapture on a microsite as well as .csv import / upload to create records in DE.**

- When records are added to the DataExtension  I want to shoot out a Email with a Link. When Subscriber clicks on Link we need to Track this as opt-In in our Data Extension

My approach would be to write a Query ( _Opens and / _sends ) activity which updates the DataExtension with information on opens and click if subscriber opened email and clicked on Link.

- Would that work out is Query Activity the right tool to use for that or is there any other Best Practice solution available?

**2.    When records are added to Data extension i need to push this data into Sales Cloud.**

- My approach would be create a Salesforce Data Extension link it to my “SebastianDE” to sync. 
  Then the Salesforce Data Extension will create Leads in SalesCloud.
- Would that work out too or is there any other best practice?

**3.    When a journey from Journey Builder started and the first email is sended out how can i determine which user opened the email?  I need to find out who opened the email to have a decision split in my Journey to distinguish who opened email and who did not open the email for further nurturing.**

- For this one I have no idea how to accomplish this. Is there a standard feature which allow me to do this? Engagement Split?

Thank you for your support and help!
I Hope these questions are not to fancy or to unordinary.

Best regards & a good start in the weekend
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your three questions:

### 1. Sending Email to Contacts that are added to Data Extension

If you want to send an email to new Contacts that have been added to a sendable DE, I'd recommend creating an Interaction in Journey Builder and set your DE as the Event Source DE. Schedule the Event (either using an Automation or the Event itself) and any new Contacts that are added to the DE will be injected into the Interaction each time the Event is fired. As a prerequisite, you will need to:

1. Configure [Data Designer](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_designer/)
2. Set the [Channel Address Order](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/contacts_configuration/) to use the email address field in your Event Source DE.

### 2. Pushing Data to Sales Cloud

Be aware that the [Data Stream](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/integrating_data_into_your_account_with_data_stream/) feature and Synchronized Data Sources does not actually *synchronize the data* into Sales Cloud, it will only synchronize fields from your Sales Cloud Object.

If you want to create a new Lead in Sales Cloud, then I would add a [Lead Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/sales_and_service_cloud_canvas_activities/lead/) to your Journey Builder Interaction, which will create and/or update a lead record in Sales Cloud for each Contact that reaches the Activity.

### 3. Tracking Users who Opened Email in Journey Builder

Use the [Engagement Split Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/use_the_engagement_split_activity/) to define whether the Contact opened the Email after a defined Wait Period.

Comment: Hi Eliot,

thank you for your hints. I got it working! I also worked with the API to push data from a Visualforce Page into a DE and fire event when Button in SF is clicked.

But now i came across Salesforce Data Extensions but cant get Data out of them int a "Normal DE" I considered using Querys to save data in another DE but i dont know how to start with the query do you may have an example or hint on how to get data form SF DE into a normal DE to use in Journey Bulder respectively where to start writing querys / Do i need Automation Studio for this?

Thank you
Best Regrads

Comment: Glad to hear that you have this working now. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted for the benefit of others. Regarding the the [SFDE](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/key_concepts/salesforce_data_extension/), you should just need to move the SFDE to the regular DE folder, then the DE will be available to link to the Contact in Data Designer.